# GlassFish how to change authentication required message

Tags: java, glassfish

I am using basic authentication, users and theirs password are stored in Realms/file. When I try to access my web page, I get the following message:

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/2iqlmpd.jpg]

I want to know if it's possible to change message text (after The server says:), for example: Please fill in you username and password... I believe I can not change entire message because it's not part of glassfish server (browser provide it) or can I?

Thank you.

Comment: I think Glassfish _is_ providing this, but it is happening at the server level (which is below the J2EE layer where you and I spend most of our time).

Comment: Thanks, so it's most likely impossible to change than (I haven't found a solution to this problem anywhere yet, not even on glassfish documentation)...

Comment: What username, password is Glassfish looking for here? I have the same problem!